# passing a method with parameters as an argument in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently need to pass some methods as parameters in order to render json properly:

```
render json: @objects.to_json(methods: [:num_of_properties])
```

This syntax currently works. However, there is another method I want to pass; this method takes in 1 argument.

I figured this would work:

```
render json: @objects.to_json(methods: [:num_of_properties, :property_is_owned_by?(current_user)])
```

This does **not** work. Is this even possible to do? I figured that if you can pass methods as arguments in the first place, you must be able to pass methods that take in arguments. But I don't know. I'm not too familiar with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echnically its not intended to give arguments to_json only takes getters. But you could do something along those lines:

```
class ObjectClassOfYourChoice
  attr_accessor :current_user

  def property_is_owned_by?(user = nil)
    user ||= current_user
    # rest of your code
  end
end


@objects.each do |object|
  object.current_user = current_user
end
render json: @objects.to_json(methods: [:property_is_owned_by?]
```

Although I wouldn't do it like this since you have to set for all the object and thats just codesmell.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky for reminding me of my typo in the method arguments and alleging me of copying an answer. I renamed the class to something way more suitable since anybody who reads this can't see that I called is `Object` because OP called his var `@objects`.